# How do you include the C++ standard library in xcode 4.3

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to use C++ code in my ios app (I really don't like objective C, I'm going to use it only when necessary [view control, etc]) and while everything seems to be working I get an error in the following test file.

```
 #ifndef prueba3_GlobalStatic_h
 #define prueba3_GlobalStatic_h
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 class GlobalStatic
 {
 public:
     GlobalStatic();
     ~GlobalStatic();
     string foo();

 private:
     int integerValue;
 };

 #endif
```

When I try to build the project the IDE gives me the following error: 
" 'string' file not found"
I've looked around but cannot find a conclusive answer; any help would be appreciated. In essence, how do I get the standard library working?

Comment: how did you compiled the code? Can you see somewhere the comandline used by the IDE?

Comment: Is the extension of the file .mm?

Comment: Note that, rather than changing the file extension, you can go into "Get Info" and change the file type.

Comment: I've tried using the default compiler as well as other C++ compilers present in the build settings for the project however the error persists. I've also tried using .mm instead of .cpp (remember I'm working with C++ files, not objective C) and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cause of missing c++ headers is including them from an objective-c context as opposed to from objective-c++ -- and you can't use the c++ stl from c! The easier solution is to simply change all your .m files to .mm, .mm will send them to the objective-c++ compiler.

Comment: My error is found within a .cpp file and its corresponding .h, must I change the .m files (the other files in my project) to .mm to make this work? I've changed the .cpp to .mm and that didn't work.

Comment: If the error is in the .h file, and that .h is included (directly or otherwise) into a .m file everything in .h file is being compiled as part of the .m context. So to answer more specifically every objective c (.m) file that includes by any means c++ code (like this header) must be sent to the objective c++ compiler (renamed to .mm)

Comment: rename .m->.mm, not .cpp->.mm, .cpp->.mm solves a different problem of including objective-c++ in a c++ file